# Electron Plasma Frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, plasma-physics

Displayed is the context
[image]

[image]

My question is, why doesn't the electric field from the electrons permeate throughout the cold plasma?

Surely there will be flux on the RHS of the boundary as there is an unbalanced amount of electric charge inside the region?

Comment: Have you looked up Debye shielding yet?  If not, start there.

Comment: I have, but in this case the rest of the charges are initially fixed so no shield could be formed?

Comment: Suppose all charges were fixed in position, would the electric field from any given one be detectable at an arbitrary distance from the source?  How far away from the source could one move before that one charge was indistinguishable from the rest?

Comment: I think this is a misuse of Gauss' theorem, surely this derivation works under the assumption that the electric field becomes negligible at a distance from the area of interest.(I don't think I mentioned this before but Gauss' theorem is used here to derive the electric charge enclosed).

Comment: How could it misuse Gauss' theorem?  You draw a pill box of your design and then compute the integral of the inner product between the enclosed electric fields and the outward normals over the surface.  Regarding your second question, yes there is an unbalanced charge density which is why there is an electric field acting as a restoring force.  Electric fields do work to get rid of themselves.

Comment: Because its implying that there is no flux on any surface except the LHS and i find the justification extremely hand-wavey considering when you super pose the fields from the separated charges its not what is described.

Comment: No, that is not how Gauss' theorem works.  You can be foolish and choose a "bad" surface if you wish, which does not contain all of the relevant charges.  It will still work and still describe fields for the charges enclosed.  The only assumption is that the charges contained are all that's necessary to explain the field at that surface.  It's a math theorem, not a physics one.  It just happens to work well with $r^{-2}$ fields like gravity and electric fields due to charge sources.

Comment: Sorry I meant Gauss' Law ie the flux integral is equal to the charge enclosed over epsilon naught, which is one of Maxwell's equations no?

Comment: Yes, that is to what I was referring.  One of Gauss' theorems allows you to convert the volume integral of that equation to the surface integral shown in the image you attached.

Comment: Yes I'm aware which is why I clarified, I still don't see how this is a correct usage of Gauss' Law, how can you say that the flux is zero on all sides except the LHS, lets imagine we put a test positive charge above the negative region, the charge is closer to the negative region than the positive thus will feel a force, ie field lines?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, why doesn't the electric field from the electrons permeate throughout the cold plasma?

Not the way you are thinking, no.  A [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) is an ionized gas but it is also quasi-neutral.  That is, there are roughly an equal number of positive and negative charges.  Because of that, the electric fields cancel out over a distance known as the [Debye length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length).  Electric fields always do work to get rid of themselves.  In the case of [Langmuir waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation) as in your example here, a *clump* of electrons oscillate through the background plasma and only in the region near the *clump* are there any unbalanced charges.

Thus, when you draw your pill box to pictorially describe what you intend to do with [Gauss' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law), you want to choose a box that makes your life easier.  You get to choose how you draw these things.  You could choose to draw a "bad" box and cause yourself all sorts of headaches, but why.  So you draw a box that extends to the quasi-neutral plasma on one side and the other sits near the unbalanced charges due to the oscillating *clump* of electrons.  Because of Debye shielding, the box edges in the quasi-neutral plasma will have no net electric field across the boundary.

> Surely there will be flux on the RHS of the boundary as there is an unbalanced amount of electric charge inside the region?

There is an unbalance on one side of the box, not all sides.  The drawing you provided in Fig. 1.2 is showing a larger region than what is implied in Fig. 1.1.  If you draw your pill box too small (e.g., the right-hand side sits near the *clump* of electrons too), then yes you have a headache figuring out the net electric flux through the boundaries.

But why make your life difficult?  You can draw the box as large as you want, so make sure one side is far far away from the *clump* of electrons and put the other right in the middle.  The side far far away has no net electric flux becuase it's in a quasi-neutral plasma.  If the plasma is cold, then the particles don't move thus there truly is no net electric flux through that boundary.  If the plasma is warm/hot, then there could be a net electric flux through some parts of the that boundary at any given instant in time due to thermal fluctuations in the positions of the particles.  However, these would average out over the boundary to a value small enough to neglect.